# Is there a way of preventing duplicate XML nodes when converting Json to XML?

Tags: xml, json, json.net, deserialization

I am using JsonConvert to deserialise a Json object to XML but because the Json has a different structure for elements at the same level I am getting duplicate nodes in my resulting XML.

My Json looks like this:

```
{
    "shipments": [
        {
            "id": "A000001",
            "name": "20141208 140652",
            "type": "OUTLET",
            "date": "2014-12-08 14:06:52",
            "status": "SENT",
            "received_at": null,
            "created_at": "2014-12-08 14:06:52",
            "updated_at": null,
            "outlet_id": "SH000064"
        },
        {
            "id": "A000002",
            "name": "20141204 122650",
            "type": "SUPPLIER",
            "date": "2014-12-04 12:26:50",
            "outlet_id": "SH000064",
            "supplier_id": null,
            "status": "RECEIVED",
            "received_at": "2014-12-04 12:28:43",
            "created_at": "2014-12-04 12:26:50",
            "updated_at": "2014-12-04 12:28:43"
        }
    ]
}
```

After conversion the XML looks like this:

```
<root>
  <shipments>
    <id>A000001</id>
    <name>20141208 140652</name>
    <type>OUTLET</type>
    <date>2014-12-08 14:06:52</date>
    <status>SENT</status>
    <received_at />
    <created_at>2014-12-08 14:06:52</created_at>
    <updated_at />
    <outlet_id>SH000064</outlet_id>
  </shipments>
  <shipments>
    <id>A000002</id>
    <name>20141204 122650</name>
    <type>SUPPLIER</type>
    <date>2014-12-04 12:26:50</date>
    <outlet_id>SH000064</outlet_id>
    <supplier_id />
    <status>RECEIVED</status>
    <received_at>2014-12-04 12:28:43</received_at>
    <created_at>2014-12-04 12:26:50</created_at>
    <updated_at>2014-12-04 12:28:43</updated_at>
    <outlet_id>SH000064</outlet_id>
  </shipments>
</root>
```

The code I'm using to convert the Json is:

```
var document = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "root");
var xml = document.OuterXml;
```

The problem is the duplication of the outlet_id node in the second shipments element. The input Json passes validation so I assume this is a common problem. Is there a way around it?

UPDATE: Further debugging shows that the extra node is being introduced during the submitting and processing of the HttpWebRequest. If I call the REST service via the Postman app I get the Json as given above (with truncation for simplicity). If I call the service via my C# code I get this instead:

```
{
    "shipments": [
        {
            "id": "A000001",
            "name": "20141208 140652",
            "type": "OUTLET",
            "date": "2014-12-08 14:06:52",
            "status": "SENT",
            "received_at": null,
            "created_at": "2014-12-08 14:06:52",
            "updated_at": null,
            "outlet_id": "SH000064"
        },
        {
            "id": "A000002",
            "name": "20141204 122650",
            "type": "SUPPLIER",
            "date": "2014-12-04 12:26:50",
            "outlet_id": "SH000064",
            "supplier_id": null,
            "status": "RECEIVED",
            "received_at": "2014-12-04 12:28:43",
            "created_at": "2014-12-04 12:26:50",
            "updated_at": "2014-12-04 12:28:43",
            "outlet_id": "SH000064"
        }
    ]
}
```

The code I am using to submit the request and process the response is:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Uri.EscapeUriString(url)) as HttpWebRequest;
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
var responseStream = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
```

A breakpoint at this stage shows that the additional node has been added to the Json returned from streaming the response.

Performing the same call where the data returned is all of the same type, and so structure, doesn't create duplicate nodes so this is, presumably, caused by the one "shipments" element having a different structure from its peers.

Comment: Your JSON has dangling commas, which suggests that you have edited out parts of it.  What you've posted does NOT pass validation (try it at [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)).  If I remove the dangling commas and try converting the JSON you've shown above into XML using the code you've posted, I do NOT get a duplicated "outlet_id" node in the XML.  I only get a duplicate node if the source JSON has duplicate data already in it.  Please check your JSON for duplicate properties.  If you still are seeing the problem, please provide a *complete, working, example program* to demonstrate.

Comment: I had edited the Json, and carelessly as you point out. I have edited my original post to show the correct abbreviated Json, now valid.

Comment: If you're getting a different result via Postman than your C# code, then there must be something different between the two web service calls.  Are you passing all the same parameters and headers each time?  I would recommend using a tool like Fiddler to watch what the HTTP request and response actually are on the wire.  You should be able to identify a difference.